# Need a SELECT query built but don't know how

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have 2 tables:

```
playerfiles        player_ips
---------------    ---------------
player_id : INT    player_id : INT
name : VARCHAR     ip : VARCHAR
```

Now I want to look up all accounts with the same IP for a given user name

Based on this user name, we should find an `id`, then based on this `IP`, a list of `IPs`, and based on that list of `IPs`, a list of `player_ids` and based on that list of `player_ids`, a list of `names`

Can somebody help?

Comment: It's basic sql.  what part of it do you not know how to do?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO)! When asking a question it helps to provide table structure, columns, expected results and how tables relate. In addition provide what you've tried. We try to avoid writing the code for you, but are all to happy to help once you get stuck. So if you could update your question with table structure, how the relate, desired results, and sample data as well as what you've tried, we'll do our best to help out. As it stands, it's difficult to help as we don't know expected results and sample data!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
SELECT playerfiles.name
FROM playersfiles
INNER JOIN player_ips
    ON playerfiles.player_id = player_ips.player_id
WHERE player_ips.ip IN (
    SELECT player_ips.ip
    FROM player_ips
    INNER JOIN playerfiles
        ON playerfiles.player_id = player_ips.player_id
            AND playerfiles.name = 'theusername'
)
```